# Cannot install R Bioconductor packages via Conda

Tags: r, conda, bioconductor, mamba

I wanted to start using Conda environments on my new computer (macOS), primarily for bioinformatic analysis. However, I cannot bring it to download Bioconda bioconductor packages.

I tried several approaches right now, but could not accomplish a succesful installation.

### Installation

I basically followed the instructions on this [website](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Starting by downlaoding mambaforge from the [github](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge) via this command:

```
curl -L -O "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh"
bash Mambaforge-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh
```

### Setup

I then created a first R environment, similar to outlined [here](https://astrobiomike.github.io/R/managing-r-and-rstudio-with-conda)

So I created an environment via:

```
mamba create -n R-4.3.0 -c conda-forge r-base r-essentials
```

And so far, everything works fine: I can activate the environment and use R.

### Problem

Now the problem arises when I try to also install a bioconductor, bioconda R-package, such as DESeq2, edger, or minfi (those are the ones I tested).

It always ends in somehow refusing to install,find the package

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - bioconductor-deseq2

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/r/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I initially tried to install it from a YAML-file, which looks like this

```
name: methylation
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
  - default
dependencies:
  - conda-forge::r-base
  - conda-forge::r-essentials
  - bioconductor-deseq2
```

or with `conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-deseq2`

I have also tried to do the same with micromamba, installed via homebrew and set my .condarc and/or .mambarc file as described on [bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/), but I make no progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- Bioconda doesn't support **osx-arm64**; you need to emulate
- `conda-forge` channel must take priority
- `default` isn't a channel; and really you don't need `defaults` unless installing really old Bioconda packages
- R 4.3 is only just rolling out on `conda-forge` and nothing on Bioconda builds for it yet

Taking that all into consideration, here is a better YAML:

**methylation.yaml**

```yaml
name: methylation
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - nodefaults  ## block user/system channels
dependencies:
  - r-base=4.2  ## always specify the R version (faster solve; more stable)
  - r-essentials
  - bioconductor-deseq2
```

To install this, we need to override your default platform **osx-arm64** and replace it with **osx-64**:

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 mamba env create -n methylation -f methylation.yaml

## set the subdir for the environment
mamba activate methylation
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
```

Note: Always activate this environment before installing packages in it - otherwise it will fall back to using `osx-arm64`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this indeed fixes the problem first try! Also thanks for the other helpful tips. I guess all the resources I watched were prior to Apple Silicon