# Uncaught_exceptions in C++ in conda is unavailable?

Tags: c++, conda, libc++

I was using Rstudio in a conda environment to install the `recount` package and when it was installing the `tzdb` dependency, I got this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘tzdb’ ...
** package ‘tzdb’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C++ compiler: ‘clang version 17.0.6’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX10.15.sdk’
clang++ -I"~/anaconda3/envs/CONDA_ENV/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'~/anaconda3/envs/CONDA_ENV/lib/R/library/cpp11/include' -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/CONDA_ENV/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I~/anaconda3/envs/CONDA_ENV/include   -I../inst/include -DINSTALL=dummy -DAUTO_DOWNLOAD=0 -DHAS_REMOTE_API=0 -DUSE_OS_TZDB=0 -DONLY_C_LOCALE=1 -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem ~/anaconda3/envs/CONDA_ENV/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1709218322135/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.3.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=~/anaconda3/envs/CONDA_ENV=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c api.cpp -o api.o
In file included from api.cpp:1:

In file included from ../inst/include/date/tz.h:99:
../inst/include/date/date.h:1067:22: error: 'uncaught_exceptions' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.12 - see https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#newer-c-features-with-old-sdk
 1067 |                 std::uncaught_exceptions() == 0 &&
      |                      ^
~/anaconda3/envs/CONDA_ENV/bin/../include/c++/v1/exception:185:63: note: 'uncaught_exceptions' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
  185 | _LIBCPP_FUNC_VIS _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTIONS int uncaught_exceptions() _NOEXCEPT;
```

I can see that `uncaught_exceptions` is made unavailable inside the exception file of the C++ standard library headers.

I understand that `uncaught_exceptions` was introduced to the `libcpp` system files in macOS 10.12+ (my version is 12.6.3), but either way, conda itself installs its own versions of the system files so this should not be an issue. I have tried to update my `libcxx` library files on conda but that did not change anything. Is it possible to change the standard library headers for C++?

Comment: `recount` is available through Bioconda (precompiled) using `conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda bioconductor-recount`. However, Bioconda doesn't yet support **osx-arm64**, so one would need to emulate if going this route, e.g., as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76473941/570918).

Comment: What language version are you compiling with C++11, C++14, C++17? Since [uncaught_exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception ) is only avialable since C++17

Comment: If you really want to try compiling in Conda environments (not my first choice), one almost certainly needs to install the `compilers` package from Conda Forge, which includes some needed environment variables to direct the compiler toward Conda's `lib/` and `include/` paths.

Comment: @PepijnKramer my clang version is 17.0.6

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to tell `date.h` to not use `std::uncaught_exceptions()`.  This is done by compiling with this option on the compiler command line:

```
-DHAS_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTIONS=0
```

Or otherwise somehow ensuring that the date configuration macro `HAS_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTIONS` is set to `0` by the time `date.h` is seen by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is that I am not performing the compilation myself, the compilation command ran above is done as part of the conda installation step. The command I ran was `BiocManager::install("recount")`.

Comment: I should also clarify that the command I ran was inside an R file that I ran.